# How to restore multiple backups

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup, restore

I'm using [ExpressMaint](http://expressmaint.codeplex.com/) and Windows Scheduled Tasks to create weekly full and daily differential backups of some MS SQL Server 2008 R2 Express databases

Weekly fulls

```
expressmaint -S (local)\SQLExpress -D ALL -T DB -R D:\Backup\Reports -RU WEEKS -RV 1 -B D:\Backup\Data -BU WEEKS -BV 4 -V -C
```

Daily Diffs

```
expressmain -S (local)\SQLExpress -D ALL -T DIF -R D:\Backup\Reports -RU WEEKS -RV 1 -B D:\Backup\Data -BU days -BV 7 -V -C
```

When I come to restore these to a certain point, I have to restore each backup individually. Is there any way I can *chain* a series of backups into a single restore that will be re-played in the correct order?

When I try this, I get the error

> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ---
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> The media loaded on "C:\Foo\Bar_FullBackup_20110130_2346.bak" is formatted to support 1 media families, but 2 media families are expected according to the backup device specification.
>   RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3231)
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.1600&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=3231&LinkId=20476

**Edit**

I am using the restore dialog from the tasks menu when you right click on a database. From there, I select "Restore from device" and Add the .bak files I wish to restore from.

If I only add a single .bak file, I'm OK, if I add multiple files, I receive the error above.

Comment: Can you show an example of the restore statement you are using?

Comment: @Eric added a little more detail

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using SSMS, you cannot chain a restore of the backups in one operation. You would have to do multiple restores. You'll want to use T-SQL in order to be more efficient.

```
--Restore the most recent full backup
RESTORE DATABASE <mydb>
FROM DISK = 'Path to full backup'
WITH NORECOVERY, STATS=10 --If only restoring the full, change to RECOVERY

--Restore the most recent diff backup
RESTORE DATABASE <mydb>
FROM DISK = 'Path to diff backup'
WITH RECOVERY, STATS=10
```

More info on RESTORE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx

Comment: You can chain backup types together via the GUI in SSMS. You add each backup file for the given database and it will verify the files and then perform the restore for you. If you use the script to new query window feature you will see similar code that is included in this answer.

Answer (score 6):

--Restore the most recent full backup

```
RESTORE DATABASE <DATABASE NAME>
FROM DISK = <Path to full backup>
WITH NO RECOVERY
```

--Restore the most recent differential backup

```
RESTORE DATABASE <DATABASE NAME>
FROM DISK = <Path to differential backup>
WITH NORECOVERY
```

--Restore all the transactional log backups which was taken after the most recent differential backup

```
RESTORE DATABASE <DATABASE NAME>
FROM DISK = <Path to first transactional log backup>
WITH NORECOVERY
```

.
.
.
.
.

```
RESTORE DATABASE <DATABASE NAME>
FROM DISK = <Path to last transactional log backup>
WITH RECOVERY
```

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to restore from a device, but what you really want to do is specify the 'From database' option in SSMS. The GUI should bring up the available backup files and you can select the full and differential files.

Comment: How does this work when I'm restoring on a different server? Do I need to tell the database which files it considers it's backups?

Comment: You won't be able to use SSMS in that way, I don't believe. You will need to script out the restore commands as Eric has suggested above.